# ImportError: No module named base during transform pygame in Pyinstaller

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, pyinstaller

I knowed that pyinstaller-2.1 is suitable working under python v2.7 not v3 onward, however I've ensured that I've already installed `pygame` package along with its dependencies found from [here](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu) .

I managed to create the `spec` file by issuing "`python makespec.py --onefile --debug pingpong.py`" and "`python build.py pingpong.spec`" without any error.

The error found is as below when I tried to execute it by issues "`./pongpong`" in the terminal for test trial.

```
LOADER: out00-PYZ.pyz
LOADER: Running scripts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/home/x/Documents/python/PyInstaller-2.1/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/x/Documents/python/PyInstaller-2.1/utils/build/pingpong/out00-PYZ.pyz/pygame", line 127, in <module>
ImportError: No module named base
LOADER: RC: -1 from pingpong
LOADER: OK.
LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
LOADER: Back to parent
LOADER: Doing cleanup
LOADER: Freeing archive status for /home/x/Documents/python/PyInstaller-2.1/utils/dist/pingpong
```

FYI, I'm working in platform ubuntu 32-bit version 13.10 for interest to explore in using pyinstaller only and I'm running successfully by using py2exe under windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem... I'm trying some legacy version of PyInstaller now to see if it improves the situation.